# .Renviron file not found in batch

Tags: r, batch-processing, package

I've got a ".Renviron" file but R can't seem to find it if I run an R file in batch mode. If I include

```
source(paste0(Sys.getenv("HOME"),"\\.Renviron"),echo=TRUE)
```

the output correctly reports

```
R_LIBS = "D:\\R\\library"
```

But the packages in this directory aren't found. I've tried `R CMD BATCH` and `Rterm.exd <` *source* > *output* `2>&1`, the package library is not found using either method. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm using R 3.3.2 under Windows 7.

Comment: Output `.libPath()` when running in Batch. What do you get?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. If I run R from the command prompt, R only loads .Renviron if it is in the directory from which I run R. My understanding is that R should search for .Renviron in the user's home directory, but it is not doing that for me.

Comment: What's really strange is that a .Rprofile file in my home directory is found. As a workaround, I created a Windows batch file which defines R_LIBS: `D:\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64\Rterm.exe --no-restore --no-save --file="%~1.R" > "%~1.out" 2>&1 R_LIBS=D:/R/library`. Kludgey but it works.

Comment: @csgillespie how do you do that? Can you please give the full line of code that should be run

Comment: Rscript -e ".libPaths()"

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue in R 3.2.0 by [creating a user environment variable](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/create-user-system-environment-variables-windows-7-windows-8) R_ENVIRON_USER that pointed to my .Renviron file.

RStudio, it seems, loads .Renviron from %userprofile%/Documents but command line R defaults to just %userprofile%.  Creating a system environment variable makes the behavior consistent for both RStudio and the command line.

See [this webpage](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200671307-Trouble-loading-Renviron-in-Windows-7-) for a further discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't have admin rights. I tried defining an environment variable in a Windows batch file but that wasn't recognized.